# Zooming In and Out using ArcPy with ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, zoom, bookmarks, camera-class

I have code that zooms a layout to a bookmark and then exports that layout to PDF. This step helps me produce maps on a large scale because I have about 40 bookmarks. However, if someone asks me to create the maps again but zoomed in or out more than that creates a problem because then I have to change all the bookmarks. I'm hoping there is some kind of code that would zoom to the bookmark and then I could tell it to zoom in or out a certain amount from there.

Here is the code I have currently:

```
import arcpy

p = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(r'C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\CenterHeatMaps.aprx')
lyt = p.listLayouts("Layout_King")[0]
mf = lyt.listElements("MAPFRAME_ELEMENT", "Map*")[0]
bkmks = mf.map.listBookmarks()
m = p.listMaps()[0]
OnLyrList = m.listLayers('Topographic')
OnNxtList = m.listLayers('Open_GoHealth_Centers')
CenterList = m.listLayers("CASum*")

#Loop through center layers that begin with 'SumWithin'
for center in CenterList:

   #Loop through all bookmarks until finding a match for the active center
    for bkmk in bkmks:       
        if bkmk.name == center.name[19:]:
            
            #Turn off all layers
               lyrList = m.listLayers()
               for lyr in lyrList:
                   lyr.visible = False

            #Turn on desired layers
               for lyr in OnLyrList:
                   lyr.visible = True
               for lyr in OnNxtList:
                   lyr.visible = True
               center.visible = True

            #Zoom to active bookmark
               mf.zoomToBookmark(bkmk)
               
            #Change Layout Title
               for elm in lyt.listElements("TEXT_ELEMENT"):
                   elm.text = "Annual_CA Summary by Block 2017 - " + center.name[19:]

            #Export to PDF
               lyt.exportToPDF(r"C:\arcGIS_Shared\Python\Export\CenterHeatMaps_CA" + "\\Annual_CA" + center.name[15:] + ".pdf")
               print(center.name[15:])
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To zoom in or out on the current extent of a map frame you should be able to use the `scale` property of the map frame's [Camera object](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/camera-class.htm).

For example, this code will zoom out 5%:

```
mf.camera.scale = mf.camera.scale * 1.05
```

or in a more concise way, as [suggested by @MarceloVilla-Piñeros](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268355/zooming-in-and-out-using-arcpy-with-arcgis-pro#comment531435_268361):

```
mf.camera.scale *= 1.05
```