# Querying for extent of layer in arcpy.mp?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, extents, camera-class

We're migrating automated mapping scripts from ArcGIS Desktop to ArcGIS Pro — Python 2.7 to 3, `arcpy.mapping` module to `arcpy.mp` module. All these scripts iterate through a loop to select various features of interest, and then focus the dataframe extent on that selection. For example:

```
gas_main_layer = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "GasMain", data_frame)[0]
data_frame.extent = gas_main_layer.getSelectedExtent()
# adjust scale slightly so view is larger than polygon extent
data_frame.scale *= 1.2
```

I easily figured out how to transition `ListLayers` to the new mapping module's workflow, but I can't find a comparable method on [the Layer class](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/arcpy/mapping/layer-class.htm) to get the selected extent and then reset the zoom/extent of its Map. What is the way to get the same functionality out of the new module?

Comment: The last bit in your code snippet of adjusting your scale a fraction is done at https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/268361/115

Comment: Thank you! Once I discovered what "controls" the extent/scale in Pro vs Desktop, it was _much_ simpler to search for solutions and figure out how to control everything I needed to.

Answer (score 5):

I found the solution in a blog on [ArcGIS Pro for Iterative Map Exports](https://www.buildingupdreams.com/blogs/post/ArcGIS-Pro-for-Iterative-Map-Exports) which is about a very similar problem.

In the `arcpy.mp` module, querying the layer extent is now a Mapframe method (and Mapframe Camera method) rather than a Layer method.

```
project  = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(aprx_file_path)
layout   = project.listLayouts("project_layout")[0]
mapframe = layout.listElements("MAPFRAME_ELEMENT", "layout_mapframe")[0]

...

# query layer extent through mapframe
layer_extent = mapframe.getLayerExtent(gas_main_layer, True)
# apply extent to mapframe camera
mapframe.camera.setExtent(layer_extent)
```

Comment: `arcpy.Describe` 's extent property can be used in finding the extent of the layer as well, e.g. `arcpy.Describe(gas_main_layer).extent`

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have layouts or are more interested in getting a map (dataframe) extent:

```
aprx=arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject("CURRENT")
mapView = aprx.listMaps()[0]
mapExtents=mapView.defaultCamera.getExtent()

print(mapExtents.lowerLeft, mapExtents.upperRight)
```

Alter to something like `.listMaps("Map Name X")[0]` to find a particular one.

And it appears [necessary to save the project first](https://community.esri.com/t5/python-questions/extent-of-map-in-arcgis-pro/m-p/367454/highlight/true#M28987) before the info becomes available.
*Hat tip to David Matthews and Joshua Bixby on Geonet.*